# Integrating certain functions over the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, surface-integrals

Let $ \mathbb{S}^2$ the unit sphere, and $  \vec a$, $  \vec b$ two constant vectors. I have to prove that: 
 $$  \iint\limits_{\mathbb{S}^2}  \langle \vec x , \vec a \rangle \langle \vec x , \vec b \rangle \, d \sigma= \frac43 π \langle \vec a , \vec b \rangle $$ and by using this to prove that: $$  \iint\limits_{\mathbb{S}^2}  \langle A\vec x , \vec x \rangle \, d \sigma = \frac{4}{3}  π  \operatorname{tr}(A) $$ where $A$ is a matrix with order $3 \times 3$.
Can anyone give me an idea about the solution?

Comment: This doesn't look like differential geometry, especially if you're talking about constant vectors and not specifying what space they are constant in. It doesn't look Riemannian either, especially since you haven't specified the Riemannian metric. Please read the tag descriptions and retag.

Answer (score 2):

$$  \iint\limits_{\mathbb{S}^2} x^2 + y^2 + z^2 d \sigma= 4 π,  $$ but he integrals of $x^2,y^2,z^2$ must be the same,  so
 $$  \iint\limits_{\mathbb{S}^2} x^2  d \sigma= 4 π / 3.  $$
After that you are looking at the polarization identities for quadratic forms. Also called parallelogram law.